# Qt QSqlDatabase

Tags: excel, qt, odbc

after searching all day, I could not find answer to my question. My question is:
Why ODBC driver returns second value, not first, code was taken from 
https://wiki.qt.io/Handling_Microsoft_Excel_file_format

In while LOOP at first step I see value of two, however in excel I have 1. Why?

Any help appreciated

The code is:

```
srcdb.setDatabaseName("DRIVER={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};DBQ=" + QString(getSettings("folderpath") + '/' + file));
        if(srcdb.open()) {
            QSqlQuery query("SELECT * FROM [" + QString("Sheet1") + "$A1:A3]"); // Select range, place A1:B5 after $
            while (query.next()) {
                QString column = query.value(0).toString();
                qDebug() << column;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Could you show us the file, and, if different from your link, some piece of code??

Answer (score 0):

Found this in the wiki:

> By default OBDC uses the first row as names for the columns, you can
>   change this whith the ‘FirstRowHasNames’ option in the connection
>   settings. Keep in mind that you are using a database and that each
>   column has his own datatype. So if your second row contains text and
>   your third row contains numbers, sql wil pick one of these datatypes.
>   If a few rows contain text and the rest of them contains floating
>   numbers, sql wil make the text appear and will make the numbers
>   disappear.

So thats why "2" is shown as first.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, actually it has to but it doesn't do that  Found this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/288343 and this: http://www.sql.ru/forum/597041/pri-importe-iz-excel-sedaetsya-pervaya-stroka-ona-idet-na-nazvaniya-stolbcov saying it's knowing bug, oohh, I'm tired of microsoft bugs :(

Comment: So even if you're keeping the first row empty the first output is always "2"? Try to add another blank line.

Comment: Have'nt seen the links (was using my phone)... Ok if it's a known bug, you have two possibilities mentioned at the Microsoft support page: Either request xls-files with a blank or dummy-line at the beginning or using JET/ISAM driver...

Comment: And your suggestion "to put blank line/cell" doesn't work, Works only if I put something. How stupid microsoft products are...

Comment: Why not giving a try to some third party libs shown at the wiki page you've linked: http://qt-project.org/wiki/Handling_Microsoft_Excel_file_format??